# Setting Custum background at progress dialog

Tags: android, andengine

Is it possible to set a background in progress dialog?? I am not using xml files. I am creating and displaying it in andengine activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of custom dialog instead of using progress dialog. Custom dialog will be a better approach to do this . Follow the [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application). You can also use

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

in the background property of the parent layout in order to make it transparent.

Hope this will solve your problem